# Covariance matrix of natural parameters and sufficient statistics in an exponential family

Tags: covariance-matrix, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family, fisher-information

Let $f(x\mid\mathbf{\theta})$ be a pmf in an exponential family, where the $\theta_i$s are natural parameters and $T_i(X)$ are sufficient statistics. We know that: $$\text{cov}(\hat\theta_i,\hat\theta_j)=[-l''(\hat\theta\mid x)]^{-1}\,.$$

In some special cases, I showed that: $$\text{cov}(T_i(X),T_j(X))=-l''(\theta\mid X)\,.$$

**Question:** Is it a *general* conclusion that in an exponential family, the natural parameters and the sufficient statistics have the relationship:

$$\text{cov}(\hat\theta_i,\hat\theta_j)\cdot\text{cov}(T_i,T_j)=I_{p\times p}$$

where $I_{p\times p}$ is an identity matrix? Or does this hold only in special cases?

Comment: Fixed parameters don't have a covariance (unless this is a Bayesian formulation, I guess). Are you talking about covariance of parameter *estimates*, $\text{cov}(\hat{\theta}_i,\hat{\theta}_j)$?